# How to debug plperl script in postgres-8.4 trigger

Tags: linux, postgresql, triggers, plperl

I am writing the plperl script function for my trigger execution. When INSERT / UPDATE happens ,my plperl script will run , in that I am dynamically forming some query based on event I receive. I wanted to print it in terminal when I do insert/update. But it does not happen. Tell  me which way i can print it.?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [elog](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plperl-database.html) function to raise notices. You can also use it to raise full errors.